# Child activity thread causes the app to be frozen on suppression

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-activity, activity-lifecycle

I organised my code as follow :

`MainMenu` (an activity) starts an intent on `Game` (another activity). `Game` sets `GamePanel` (a surface holder) which starts `GameThread` (a thread).

**MainMenu.java** :

```
public void buttonPlay(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Game.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

**Game.java** :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(new GamePanel(this));
}
```

**GamePanel.java** :

```
@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
    gameThread = new GameThread(surfaceHolder, this);
    gameThread.setRunning(true);
    gameThread.start();
}
@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
    gameThread.setRunning(false);
    try {
        gameThread.join();
        gameThread = null;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
}
```

**GameThread.java**

```
@Override
public void run() {
    while (running) {
        frameDelay.setStart();
        canvas = null;
        try {
            canvas = this.surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
            synchronized (surfaceHolder) {
                this.gamePanel.update();
                this.gamePanel.draw(canvas);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        finally {
            if (canvas != null) {
                try {
                    surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
            }
        }
        try {
            sleep(frameDelay.setDelay());
        } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        frameDelay.displayFPS();
    }
    try {
        sleep(1000000);
    } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
}
```

The problem occurs when I go back from the `Game` activity. The application displays the `MainMenu` activity but doesn't respond anymore and soon the system ask to kill it. Besides that the activities and the thread runs fine.

I don't know if its an activity life-cycle or a thread issue. When I don't start `GameThread` at all, the application runs fine. But `GamePanel` *surfaceDestroyed* is called so I assume the thread is properly stopped.

I tried to call :

- `Game` *onDestroy* catching the back button.
- `Game` *finish* catching the back button.
- `Game` *onDestroy* through *onPause*.
- `Game` *finish* through *onPause*.
- *interrupt* on GameThread.

None of the above solve anything (and some causes crashes).

This error occurs right when I open the application and when it is killed :

```
E/WindowState(3143): Error happens during resized 
E/WindowState(3143): android.os.DeadObjectException
E/WindowState(3143):    at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(NativeMethod)
E/WindowState(3143):    at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:496)
E/WindowState(3143):    at android.view.IWindow$Stub$Proxy.resized(IWindow.java:333)
E/WindowState(3143):    at com.android.server.wm.WindowState.reportResized(WindowState.java:1420)
E/WindowState(3143):    at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.performLayoutAndPlaceSurfacesLockedInner(WindowManagerService.java:10129)
E/WindowState(3143):    at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.performLayoutAndPlaceSurfacesLockedLoop(WindowManagerService.java:8887)
E/WindowState(3143):    at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.performLayoutAndPlaceSurfacesLocked(WindowManagerService.java:8829)
E/WindowState(3143):    at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.access$400(WindowManagerService.java:164)
E/WindowState(3143):    at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService$H.handleMessage(WindowManagerService.java:7782)
E/WindowState(3143):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/WindowState(3143):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
E/WindowState(3143):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
E/WindowState(3143):    at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46)
```

And when the app doesn't respond :

```
E/ActivityManager(3143): ANR in com.game.app (com.game.app/.MainMenu)
E/ActivityManager(3143): PID: 27828
E/ActivityManager(3143): Reason: Input dispatching timed out (Waiting to send non-key event because the touched window has not finished processing certain input events that were delivered to it over 500.0ms ago.  Wait queue length: 5.  Wait queue head age: 5534.6ms.)
```

---

**EDIT SOLUTION :**

I finally found the issue ! It came from the last sleep in my *run* method in `GameThread`, removing it solves the issue (and will not be missed for it bears no purpose). If someone can explain how that milliseconde can causes the app to freeze completely, feel free !

Comment: I added the Logcat. Thank you for taking a look on my issue !

Comment: Are you sure that this log all you have? I guess, there should be more.

Comment: This is the Logcat with a filter on my app, which I assume now is a bad practice because I didn't see the error display by the system (I added it on the post). I isolated it by repeating the bug point and it occurs right before I have to kill the app. I hope it narrows down where my mistake is, I still don't see the solution...

Answer (score 0):

[DeadObjectException](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/DeadObjectException.html) occurs when you call a dead object. I suspect your thread is running when onSurfaceDestroyed happens. Your thread uses surfaceholder as input and if it makes a call even once when it s destroyed, it may produce this error. Why do you have a while condition. What if it is not satisfied and thread runs without destroyed surfaceholder. I cant see your thread class but i guess you should put             gameThread.setRunning(false); before while loop.

Comment: When the thread is running it Log the average FPS (the multiples 30 in Logcat) which it stops doing when I back out. Plus I have a Log in this while to make sure join() (which is just after) had been called. Thus I assumed the thread was successfully stopped.

Comment: Now what's interesting is that I deliberately not stopped the thread to see if I would obtain a different behavior and test your hypothesis. And doing so it fixed the freezing problem (too bad I have a wild thread now) ! I don't see the link but there's a lead I can follow at least...

Comment: I put a while loop in case the try block fails, to make sure the thread is stopped. I don't know if it's good practice though... And good call on the setRunning() method, I moved it out. Thank you for the advice !

Comment: I do now, it doesn't seem to have any effect... If I trust the Log, it comes through it one single time anyway so I don't think it causes any trouble.

Comment: since i cant see rest of the code it is hard to say what is the reason. But the point is you are calling dead surfaceholder somewhere probably inside thread. make sure there is no surfaceholder object outside your "running" flag inside thread. So it cannot call holder when you set running false.

Comment: There's nothing outside the loop controlled by "running". To make sure I even commented out the code related to the surfaceHolder. It changes neither the behavior nor the error reports.